# OnCreate Functions not firing but OnWrite Functions fire

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an oncreate function that doesn't seem to fire when I create data in my realtime database. I understand onCreate is used when new data is created in the Realtime Database. See code below.

What am I doing wrong?

```
exports.getNewReport = 
functions.database.ref('/Hotel_Complaints/Users/{usersId}/')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  var user_id = context.params.usersId;
console.log(user_id);
// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var eventSnapshot = snapshot.val();

var device_token = admin.database().ref('/Hotel_Staff/'+user_id+'/device_token').once('value');

return device_token.then(result => {

var token_id = result.val();

console.log(token_id);

var str = eventSnapshot.issue_description;

var payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "New complaint",
        body: "New complaint for your department",

    }   

};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(function (response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });

});
});
```

[See log here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfBIG.png)

Comment: try removing the last / in the ref

Answer (score 1):

By slightly adapting your promises chaining, it should do the trick, see below:

```
exports.getNewReport = functions.database.ref('/Hotel_Complaints/Users/{usersId}/')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        var user_id = context.params.usersId;
        console.log(user_id);
        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        var eventSnapshot = snapshot.val();

        var device_token = admin.database().ref('/Hotel_Staff/' + user_id + '/device_token').once('value');

        return device_token
            .then(result => {

                var token_id = result.val();

                console.log(token_id);

                var str = eventSnapshot.issue_description;

                var payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: "New complaint",
                        body: "New complaint for your department"
                    }
                };

                // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);
            })
            .then(response => {
                // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
                // contents of response.
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                return null;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                return null
            });

    });
```

Comment: The response I get from my console is "parsing error". Is there any mistake?

Comment: I have fixed the error now but still I am not getting the notification when the function is fired. I have added a picture to the post.

Comment: The picture you have added shows a log item concerning the deployment of your Cloud Function, not its execution. Do you see other items in the log? For example do you see the result of `console.log(user_id);`? Can you show an image of your database with a new user under `/Hotel_Complaints/Users/{usersId}/`?

Comment: Do you look at the Cloud Function logs, on the Firebase console? Are you sure that you create a new user under `/Hotel_Complaints/Users/{usersId}/`?